# Average of last n or 10 rows only in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, average

[image: SQL Image]

I have a result set from a query. Let's say it contains 100 rows, with 2 columns. I want a third computed column as the average of the last 10 rows. So like this:

```
Hours     Pay    Last10Avg
--------------------------
10      1
20      2
30      3
40      4
50      5
60      6
70      7  
80      8
90      9
100     10   (550/55)= 10
110     11
...       
200     20    (1550/155) = 10
```

So for every 10 rows I want to basically get average. I mean 1 to 10 get average. 11 to 20 get average. How do I get that(the value  '10' in this example at every 10th row)?

Other info:

```
550 = 10+20+..100
55 = 1+2+..10
1550 = 110+120+...200
155 = 10+11+...20
```

Comment: look up the LAG function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can partition data by `FLOOR(ROWNUMBER/10)` to count that average.

Example query:

```
SELECT 
    T.Hours,
    T.Pay, 
    -- Use case to count avg only for 1 out of 10 rows
    CASE WHEN Idx % 10 = 0 THEN AVG(Hours/Pay) 
        OVER (PARTITION BY FLOOR((Idx-1)/10)) ELSE NULL END Avg

FROM (
    SELECT 
        T.Hours,
        T.Pay, 
        -- In order by specify order you need, use (SELECT 0) to keep db order
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) Idx
    FROM [YourTable] T
) T
```

Working sample: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20091

Comment: You have everything in example query - it is row number.

Comment: I am getting error at OVER (Partition... I am using CTE. My result set for the total result gets pulled from a table i created using CTE. Look at the image of SQL I am attaching.(First line in the question "image for sql")

Comment: I was looking at your fiddle for the last 10 rows (11...0),(5..14) it should be 495/95= 5.2. But your value shows 4. Also I replaced the 1 with the actual AVG(/) .Some result shows up, but its incorrect.

Comment: I was counting AVG instead of SUM(Hours)/SUM(Pay), that's way results was different. Try this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20128 . Also I don't see the problem with CTE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/20131

Answer (score 4):

This is what range partitioning does.  If you are using SQL Server 2012 or greater, you can simply do:

```
select hours, pay,
       (sum(hours) over (order by hours range between 9 preceding and current row) /
        sum(pay) over (order by hours range between 9 preceding and current row)
       ) as thirdcol
from table t;
```

This puts the moving average on every row, so it is not exactly the same format as the question, but it seems more useful.

Answer (score 0):

Just a non-2012 solution.

```
DECLARE @PageSize INTEGER;

SET @PageSize = 10;

WITH cteRanked
AS
(
    SELECT      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Hours) AS RID,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Hours) % @PageSize AS ModValue,
                Hours,
                Pay
    FROM        Table1
),
cteWindows
AS
(
    SELECT      r1.RID AS StartRID,
                r2.RID AS EndRID
    FROM        cteRanked r1 INNER JOIN cteRanked r2
                ON  r1.RID = r2.RID - (@PageSize - 1)
    WHERE       r1.ModValue = 1
)

SELECT      r.Hours,
            r.Pay,
            SUM(r2.Hours) / SUM(r2.Pay) AS Last10Avg
FROM        cteRanked r LEFT JOIN cteWindows w
            ON  r.RID = w.EndRID
            LEFT JOIN cteRanked r2
            ON  r2.RID BETWEEN w.StartRID AND w.EndRID
GROUP BY    r.Hours,
            r.Pay
ORDER BY    r.Hours,
            r.Pay;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,
Used for last N(4) Records Average

```
with cte (a,b) as
(
select sum(hours),sum(pay) from mytable
where Hours not in(
select top (
(select COUNT(*) from
 mytable)-4
)Hours from mytable)
)
select a/b from cte;
```